# change / update odom_combined

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, odom-combined

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
i beam my robot with set model state to move it in gazebo to different positions and then make a laserscan.
now my problem is, that the odom_combined isn't updated because it doesn't move to the position only beamed.
so i need to change my odom_combined, but i don't know really how.
i tried it with nav_msgs::Odometry but it does not make anything.
can someone help?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12231/change-/-update-odom_combined/) by [el_loco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1496/el_loco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Odometry is guaranteed to evolve over time in a continuous matter. So when your robot jumps for some reason (either you move the model in simulation, or your localization snaps the robot back in place), the odometry will not follow this jump.  See this link for more details: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0